# Getting config file values from the database

Tags: codeigniter

Has anyone ever tried to populate their config file through info from the database in CI? I'm asking since I'm making a *Settings* page for one of my apps. The idea is that the config file starts out as blank until a user signs in. All user settings are then saved to that config file for easy retrieval.

### Edit

Now that I've posted this, it seems somewhat wrong to do so. What can I do instead?

Comment: How can your app run if you've not set any CI config settings? Is this a user config or the config for the CI ... installation?

Comment: It's a custom config file. Right now I'm leaning more towards using Sessions instead.

Comment: Interfacing this at all with CI's config system is a bad idea.  CI's config system is for application settings, not user settings.  My recommendation would be to make a table and Model for user settings.  You can set up the Model to load all of the user's settings into a session if they aren't loaded, and then have it return settings from the session.